# Why SMTP service should be started for email receiving?

Tags: windows-server-2003, smtp, pop3

Windows Server 2003, SP2. Configured both mail services POP3 and SMTP. And found, that when SMTP service is stopped, pop3 service doesnt receiving email messages... outlook express is configured to use local pop3 server and remote smtp service - so no need to have smtp localy, but.. when smtp service is stopped, outlook express checks for new mail, login succesfully, found no no messages and logout, BUT i sent some test messages before this! and then i'll start smtp service messages are arriving again.. can't understand why these services are related...

Answer (score 2):

The POP3 service does not receive mail, it only serves it to POP3 clients.

The SMTP service receives the email, then writes it to disk in a folder which is later read by the POP3 service when a POP3 client looks for mail.